# sharpPDF Table Headers using Turkish character error

Tags: c#, turkish, sharppdf

when I try to write headers, it gives me that error message:

```
{"StartIndex cannot be less than zero.\r\nParameter name: startIndex"}
```

I discovered that it is about Turkish Character in the headers of tables. It runs when I don't use Turkish Ch. however.

Is there a way to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

you can try to force your culture

```
// Changes the CurrentUICulture of the current thread to en-US for example. 
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo( "en-US", false );
```